# Tags on meta.CV about "questions"

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-excerpt, meta

Cross Validated Meta has four related tags and I am trying to understand them. I believe they are different (at least some of them) but not sure how. Tag excerpts do not exist for these yet.

[questions](/questions/tagged/questions) (x6 threads)
[asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions) (x2)
[specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) (x2)
[essential-questions](/questions/tagged/essential-questions) (x6)

This thread is to ask for support about how to use the above tags correctly.

Comment: Just FYI: SE convention is not to include things like 'thanks', 'hope that helps', signature, etc. (although we still do it from time to time).

Comment: @gung. I usually remove greetings and signatures, but feel uncomfortable to not add a simple "thanks". However, you are right. I appreciate the hint.

Comment: I recognize the sentiment. I also feel obliged to add "thanks" when I ask a question here or on SO (the long reach of my Mother, no doubt). Really, it's nice that people have that instinct. Nonetheless SE discourages it: The idea is that the immediate Q & A interaction is just a vehicle for the true purpose of generating permanent, high-quality, factual information for future use by others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some time has passed and it was possible to observe how the above cited tags evolved.

After a more carefully reading I came up with this proposal:

1. The CV tag [questions](/questions/tagged/questions) (x8, +2) seems to label threads similarly to the main Stack Exchange site. Here it is their tag excerpt:

   > For questions regarding the nature of a "question" on StackExchange sites; e.g. how to ask, whether specific questions are appropriate, etc.

   We could also import/adapt the current detailed [tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/questions/info) from it.
2. Both tags [asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions) (x2, +0) and [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) (x2, +0) did not evolve and at least 3 of them would be just ok tagged as "questions".
3. The [essential-questions](/questions/tagged/essential-questions) (x6, +0) tag labels threads discussing about Cross Validated launching features such as: logo, promotion, moderators, faq, etc.

   They have in common to be originated during the private-beta (pre-launching) phase. Here I propose a complement to give emphasis on that (either on tag name or tag excerpt).

**Proposal Summary**

1. "questions" - import tag excerpt from the main SE Meta site.
2. "asking-questions" and "specific-question" - make synonyms of "questions".
3. "essential-questions" - create excerpt with something similar to:

   > questions involving Cross Validated SE preparation for the public phase

Comment: +1, these are good suggestions. I might add that we could put something like "this tag is now defunct; please do not use it" at the end of your excerpt for `[essential-questions]`.

Comment: Point 2 should be ok now.